sum subset of rows within a data frame using dplyr
Somehow I get an error in dplyr when I try to sum a previous rows within a group.
I tried to reconstruct the problem outside dplyr and it works fine without errors. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?
I have a data frame with start and end position within a string. I match patterns of different length (nchar). For each row I want to find the position (1 before pattern) in the original text without the length of the previous pattern length... So first pattern starts at 3 (4-1), second pattern starts at 9 (21-1-11) and third at 28 (50-1-sum(11,10))
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  id=1,
  start=c(4, 21, 50),
  end=c(14, 30, 60),
  nchar=c(11,10,11)
) 
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(pos=start[row_number()] -
           (1 + sum(nchar[0:(row_number() - 1)])))

Produces
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   id [1]
     id start   end nchar   pos
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    14    11     3
2     1    21    30    10    20
3     1    50    60    11    49
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
i In argument: `pos = start[row_number()] - (1 + sum(nchar[0:(row_number() - 1)]))`.
i In group 1: `id = 1`.
Caused by warning in `0:(row_number() - 1)`:
! numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used 

What I would expect for the new column to be like
sapply(1:3, function(i) df$start[i] - (1 + sum(df$nchar[0:(i - 1)])))

Which gives the correct position...

In general you should avoid using bracket subsetting [ within dplyr verbs. In this case you can get the desired output by using cumsum() to sum over rows iteratively and lag() to access the previous row:
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(pos = start - 1 - cumsum(lag(nchar, default = 0)))

gets you the desired output:
# Groups:   id [1]
     id start   end nchar   pos
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    14    11     3
2     1    21    30    10     9
3     1    50    60    11    28

